# iPhone: Error in copyItemAtPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am trying to copy a file from one folder to another folder in documents directory like this:

```
    - (void)saveFile:(NSString *)folderPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"destination.png"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *srcPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.png"];


    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }

    if (success == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Copied");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Copied");
    }
}
```

When i log error, it gives me the following message:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x9d665a0 {NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/BC37C9D7-7995-47C1-8131-2B07BADCBECB/Documents/foldername/B713320C-2CA0-4FD3-93F6-71D76B102B83/src.png, NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/BC37C9D7-7995-47C1-8131-2B07BADCBECB/Documents, NSUnderlyingError=0x9d41c60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
```

Comment: just read the error carefully your answer is in the error file with that name already exist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Issue 1:**
The issue occurred because, the directory already contains a file with same file name.

You should check whether the file exist in the folder or not like:

```
- (void)saveFile:(NSString *)folderPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"destination.png"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *srcPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.png"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    {
        //removing file
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dataPath error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not remove old files. Error:%@",error);
        }
    }
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];
    if (success == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Copied");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Copied %@", error);
    }
}
```

Issue 2:
You must provide a file name not a directory.

Replace:

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
```

With:

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];
```

Answer (score 3):

`copyItemAtPath`: is giving error as that file is already exist in that location. So you should do this before you copy file.

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: srcPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: srcPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
```

With:

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];
```